# Making the Bootstrap 3 Carousel a single static image that the text slides over

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I was curious to how I could make the Carousel a single static image that the text slides over rather than it being a bunch of images that changes with the text.

IE: When clicking the next slide button, it's only the text that moves, the image stays the same and doesn't move.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <!-- Indicators -->
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          </ol>
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
              <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="First slide">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                  <h1>Example headline.</h1>
                  <p>Note: If you're viewing this page via a <code>file://</code> URL, the "next" and "previous" Glyphicon buttons on the left and right might not load/display properly due to web browser security rules.</p>
                  <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAGZmZgAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Second slide">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                  <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
                  <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                  <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAFVVVQAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Third slide">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                  <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
                  <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                  <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
        </div><!-- /.carousel -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way:

*You remove image from carousel items, and affect an image in the carrousel-inner `background property` in css.*

**[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/I1E0rYa4f0)**

**CSS:**

```
.carousel-inner{
   background-image: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3e/Tux-G2.png");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height:200px;
  }

  .carousel-caption{
     top:1em; 
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="span8">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item">

                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h4>First Thumbnail label</h4>
                    <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item active">

                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h4>Second Thumbnail label</h4>
                    <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">

                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h4>Third Thumbnail label</h4>
                    <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```